# MongoDB master/master replication

Tags: mongodb

I want to know how to configure 2 servers Master/Master in MongoDB. I have two server on different location. How can i configure it ?

MongoDB version 4.2
Ubuntu 18.04

Is it possible to connect like mysql ? I mean domain:27017

Comment: MongoDB replication allows _a_ Primary and multiple secondary and arbiter nodes.  All writes and reads happen with the Primary. Data is replicated from the primary node to the secondaries. The default behavior for reads can be changed with Read Preference configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be only one Primary in a replicaset (The primary node is the node that accepts writes/updates/deletes)

If you used sharding (**for example** so each shard will serve a different set of countries) -  then each shard has a primary node to serve specific countries. (Note - The data in seperate **shards** does not overlap. Each shard will retain different data)